# "Simply" determining Java Radio Button id

Tags: java, netbeans, components

I'm hoping that Java is not as in-elegant as my efforts with it lead me to believe.

I am working with JRadioButtons, and want to programmatically determine an "ID" associated with them.  For this, I am trying to read "name" as listed in its NetBeans properties.

In the ide, when I right-click the component, I am given the option of "Change Variable Name..."  I use this to set values such as rb1, rb2, etc.

But in the properties panel, there is also the "name" entry which can be set to a different value.  I use this to set "id"-s such as 1, 2, etc.

Working with radio buttons, I know that I can have a series of if-statements that, in a handler, ask

```java
Object src = evt.getSource();
int val=-1;
     if (src == rb1) { val=1; }
else if (src == rb2) { val=2; }
else if (src == rb3) { val=3; }
else                 { val=4; }
```

But, besides requiring me to hard code the id value with the control name myself, where I'm prone to make a transcription error, I want to believe that there is simpler single-statement means to achieve this, something like:

```java
String name = rbGroup.getSelection().getName();
                                    .getText();
                                    .getLabel();
```

But, I seem to be stuck with the much less elegant and verbose use of multiple if-else statements.

How can I query the control to give me the properties listed in the NetBeans IDE in the simplest means possible?

Comment: Wow, I'm kind of disappointed at the willingness of some to downvote my question as 

  "unclear or lacking research effort."

I've got working code and I'd spent more than an hour researching this on stackOverflow and in google before posting.  I'd attempted to write in a lucid manner.  Perhaps it is because I tried to read from an event when I really want to be able to query components outside of the handler.

After experience with c# and other languages which make this process relatively simple, I'd hoped for a *better* way to achieve this result with Java.

Comment: Afterall, with c#, I can get the selected radio button at any time:
    RadioButton myRB = myRBG.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().FirstOrDefault(r => r.Checked);

I can also easly get its name, AccessibleName, or any other property for it:
    Console.WriteLine(myRB.AccessibleName.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(myRB.Name.ToString());

But, I don't seem to be able to do so in Java.

Comment: the problem is not with java, but swing.  in any event, actioneventlistener is probably what you want.  click a radio button, something happens.  each button gets its own listener.  much easier in netbeans, which seems to be what you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use the Action Command of the button:

```
rb1.setActionCommand("1");
```

Then in the event handler you can juse use:

```
String command = evt.getActionCommand();
```

The action command defaults to the text of the button if you don't set it explicitly.

Comment: That works great.  Unfortunately, I am not doing this processing at the time when the radio button is clicked but when a separate "Action" button is pressed.  At that time, I will have to query multiple sets of radio buttons and other controls to determine their settings to perform the appropriate action.  Short of doing those getActionCommands on the event and storing their values for later processing, is there not a means to similarly interrogate any control at any time to determine its properties?

Comment: @user2340426, You can use the `ButtonGroup.getSelection()` method. Then you can use the `ButtonModel.getActionCommand()` to get the command.

Comment: That worked perfectly.  The only hitch I had was that the #s that were set in NetBeans property panel for the ActionCommand disappeared.  Had to set in constructor.  Oh well, at least it works.  Thank you.